# Regex in Notepad++ to move contents of an element to an attribute value

Tags: regex, notepad++, href

I'm trying to solve a regex riddle. Let's say I have rows of hrefs looking like this:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/5et46ffd5e3wR23">anchor1.in</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/6utr4dGHJ6wFL">an3.php</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/k543sk6k3F6hJ">setup.exe</a>
```

What I want the regex (or any other solution) to do is to take the `href` title and copy it over to the actual url with a foward slash in front of it.

A successful result would become:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/5et46ffd5e3wR23/anchor1.in">anchor1.in</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/6utr4dGHJ6wFL/an3.php">an3.php</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/k543sk6k3F6hJ/setup.exe">setup.exe</a>
```

If you can solve this please explain how you did it.

Comment: Check out http://www.regexr.com - it lets you edit regular expressions and see their results live! See if you can first match the anchor element, then try grouping, and finally try replacing the groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
(<a\s+href=")(.*?)(">)(.*?)(<\/a>)
```

And replace with:

```
\1\2/\4\3\4\5
```

See [DEMO and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/tA9dT2/4)